# Hamilton path and minimum degree

Tags: graph-theory

$n$ is a number of vertices in graph $G, n≥4$.

Prove that if $\;\operatorname{min deg}(G) \geq \frac{(n-1)}{2}\,$ then $G$ has a Hamilton path.

Comment: I think this is  Dirac's theorem

Comment: No, it doesn't work. In Dirac's theorem assumption is not satisfied. And Ore's theorem also doesn't work
$\frac{n-1}{2}$ + $\frac{n-1}{2}$ ≥ n
n-1 ≥ n
false

Comment: Maybe a proof of Ore's Theorem could be modified to get the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ be a given graph with $n$ vertices such that $\min \deg G \ge \frac{n-1}{2}$. Create a new graph $G'$ by add another vertex $w$ to $G$ and connect it to all vertices of $G$. Note that

- $\min \deg G' = \min \deg G + 1 \ge \frac{n+1}{2}$, and
- number of vertices in $G'$ is at least $5$.

So, we can apply [Dirac's theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirac%27s_Theorem), deducing that $G'$ has a Hamiltonian circle. Back to graph $G$, it has a Hamiltonian path obtained by removing $w$ and all its edges from $G'$ (thus breaking the cycle, but leaving all the vertices of $G$ in it).

Comment: In your graf @Vedran Šego exist Hamilton path. It shouldn't be cycle. All is correct.

Comment: Sorry, mixed it with a cycle. The argument still holds, though. I'll repair it now.

Comment: Now it looks ok for me! Thank you! It was much easier than I supposed.:)